# Ran into an issue with javascript canvas graphics and motion

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm creating a JavaScript canvas game and ran into an issue. I'm creating motion by changing an object's position, clearing the canvas, and then redrawing the object. For the code I've provided, the ball element moves fine but when the rectangle moves the previous element is not deleted. This results in a line being drawn down the screen. If anyone sees what I need to fix please let me know.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var p1;
var p2;
var ball;

p1 = new rectangle(10, 120, "black", 10, 120);
p2 = new rectangle(10, 120, "black", 1180, 120);
ball = new circle(600, 580, 10, "blue");

function gameupdate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  movep1();
  moveball();
}

function rectangle(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.color = color;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

function circle(x, y, r, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;
  this.color = color;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function moveball() {
  ball.y += -3;
  ball.x += 3;
  new circle(ball.x, ball.y, 10, "blue");
}

function movep1() {
  p1.y += 1;
  new rectangle(p1.x, p1.y, "black", p1.width, p1.height);
}

setInterval(gameupdate, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: What browser are you using, because some browsers require a different way to clear the canvas. For example, older browsers require you to do `canvas.width = canvas.width` which clears the entire canvas by resizing it.

Comment: **TYPO**: in `movep1` you call `new rectangle(p1.x, p1.y, "black", p1.width, p1.height)` while it's declared as `function rectangle(width, height, color, x, y)` `x, y` and `width, height` are inverted, so your code only changes the rectangle's height. [minimal fix](https://jsfiddle.net/hfwn94uk/) However, you'd be better not generate `new` shapes every time and rather just redraw the one you created at init, and also don't use `setInterval` when doing visual animation, prefer a `requestAnimationFrame` loop. [better fix](https://jsfiddle.net/hfwn94uk/1/)

Answer (score -1):

So it's working fine on my machine, however, you may be using an older browser so use `canvas.width = canvas.width` to clear the canvas along with `ctx.clearRect()`. I also noticed that you were attempting to make a class but it was more of a function, so I turned it into a class.

I recommend you use ES6 classes because they make life so much easier and make code much cleaner. Here are some places to start learning about ES6 classes:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
- https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/classes-es6/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wWq6e6jz0g

Here's the code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('ctx');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var p1;
var p2;
var ball;

p1 = new Rectangle (10,120, "black", 10, 120);
p2 = new Rectangle (10, 120, "black", 1180, 120);
ball = new Circle (600,580,10,"blue");

function gameupdate() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
canvas.width = canvas.width;
movep1();
moveball();
drawAll();
}

function Rectangle (width,height,color,x,y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;

    this.draw = function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
    }  

    return this;
} 

function Circle (x,y,r,color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.color = color;

    this.draw = function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r,0, 2* Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    

    return this;
}

function moveball () {
    ball.y += -3;
    ball.x += 3;
}

function movep1 () {
    p1.y += 1;
}

function drawAll() {
    p1.draw();
    p2.draw();
    ball.draw();
}

setInterval(gameupdate,10);
```

```css
#ctx {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
```

Hope this helps!